# The FastAPI server built with python get stuck after idle for a long time

Tags: python, rest, fastapi

I'm building REST API service with FastAPI using Python, after I launched the API service and come back later, the API endpoint stop responding.

I open the API document with built-in: http://127.0.0.1:5000/docs, the Chrome browser took a lot of time waiting but no response. It seems the API server is closed or not connecting.

Eventually I get back to the running API command line window, pressed Ctrl+C to stop the API server. It was then that the API continued responding and do the work, showing that it received the GET request via URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/docs I've done in the previous step.

I don't understand why the FastAPI would stuck after idle for a while, and why does pressing Ctrl+C makes it continue running.

Here is my code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

def train_model(tasks):
   x = tasks.train_data
   y = tasks.train_label

   model = LinearRegression()
   model.fit(x, y)

   score = model.score(x, y)
   print("Score:", score)
   return None


@app.post("/create")
async def train(tasks, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(train_model, tasks)
    return {"Received training request":True}


if __name__ = "__main__":
   uvicorn.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 5000)
```

Comment: Did you try looking into Network tab in Browser Devtools to check what request takes too long to finish?

Comment: No, I have not try that. I thought the problem may be caused by the API server itself. This "API not respond" problem not only happens when using browser to send request, but also happens when I send request by POSTMan. I could try your advice later.

Comment: Any resolution to why this is happening? I am facing the exact same issue. I'm not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Today I used a tool PM2 to launch my API, this is a tool used to monitor APP service and auto-restart the program when the APP fails.

After I launch the API with pm2: `pm2 start main.py`

The problem that API would stuck is not happening anymore. I thought it might because pm2 restart my API when it fails, but in the dashboard didn't show any  restart action.

Now I could work with my API, but I still haven't figure out what's the cause of the previous problem. It should work fine without pm2.

Comment: Did you figure out why this happened? I am facing the same issue.